# Need Help Parsing a string in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I am working on a python project and need to parse the following string

```
{u'max(if(exists(comptPrice),add(0.010,min(0.020,mul(0.200,div(comptPrice,100.0)))),0),0)': 0.026}
```

Now there are many lines like this and i want to iterate through each of them and store only the number part after the " : " in the array  .In This case 0.026 . How can this be done . I am really new to python so excuse me if its a stupid question .

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have tried the split method but it divides the string in two parts . and then i process that and get the desired result  . I just want to know if there's a way where i only get the right hand part of the splited string in the array  which would eliminate two times processing

Comment: If you have already solved it and are looking for improvements, try Code Review.

Comment: `string.split(':')[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number is always after the final `:` in each string and that the number is always followed by `}`

```
def my_parser(s):
    parsed_s = s.split(': ')[-1][:-1]
    return s
```

of if you want the result as a float:

```
def my_parser(s):
    parsed_s = float(s.split(':')[-1][:-1])
```

Then use a list comprehension:

```
my_list_of_strings = [] #Assume already populated
my_floats = [my_parser(x) for x in my_list_of_strings]
```